# .style only affecting 1 of all classes

Tags: javascript

I have a simple function that should change the style of all elements of a specific class, but it only changes one class.

```
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
<small class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.<smallp>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

var listEl = document.querySelector('.test');
function myFunction() {

    listEl.style.color="red";
}
```

Why does it only change one class?

Comment: `querySelector()` only returns the first match.

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll` and **iterate** the list returned by it.

Comment: Why don't you just use CSS?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `querySelectorAll`. 
`querySelector` returns only first occurrence

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and use a loop to go through your results instead :

```js
var listEl = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

function myFunction() {
  for(el of listEl) el.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
<small class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.<smallp>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) returns the first match only. Look into [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead

Answer (score 0):

Use `querySelectorAll` and `forEach`

```
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach( s => s.style.color = "red");
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach( s => s.style.color = "red");
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
<small class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.<smallp>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

`querySelector()` only returns the first match. `querySelectorAll()` will return all matches, but then you have to loop over them.

```js
var listEl = document.querySelectorAll('.test');

function myFunction() {

  Array.from(listEl).forEach(el => el.style.color = "red");
}
```

```html
<p class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</p>
<small class="test">Lorem ipsum dolor sit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit.<smallp>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```